# Unable to load more than 400,000 markers in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, leaflet

I need help with my custom map using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com). I want to test load up to a 1,000,000 markers in the custom map, but I can't get above 400,000 markers. I have checked the error logs and nothing appears to show any errors. I have also set the max execution time to 300 seconds and the memory limit to 1536MB.

Markers.php is a PHP file that dynamically loads all the markers from the database and outputs in JavaScript. I'm currently using jQuery's getScript function to load the markers.php file and then set up the map after loading.

markers.php

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

...

$n = $_GET['n'] ? $_GET['n'] : 50;

try {
    $n1 = round($n / 2);
    $n2 = $n - $n1;
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die('Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n");
}

try {
    $markers1 = select("*", "`properties-ca`", "", "LIMIT 0,$n1");
    $markers2 = select("*", "`properties-fl`", "", "LIMIT 0,$n2");
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n");
}

echo 'var addressPoints1 = [';

try {
    foreach ($markers1 as $m) { 
        echo "[{$m['latitude']}, {$m['longitude']}, \"{$m['address']}, {$m['city']}, {$m['state']}\"],";
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n");
}

echo '];';

echo 'var addressPoints2 = [';

try {
    foreach ($markers2 as $m) { 
        echo "[{$m['latitude']}, {$m['longitude']}, \"{$m['address']}, {$m['city']}, {$m['state']}\"],";
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n");
}

echo '];';

...
```

index.php

```
...

<script>
    //$n is the number of markers to load
    $.getScript("markers.php?n=<?=$n?>", function(){  
        Set up map here after loading markers.php
    });
</script>

...

for (var i = 0, l = addressPoints1.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var m = new PruneCluster.Marker(addressPoints1[i][0], addressPoints1[i][1], {title: addressPoints1[i][2]},/^\d+$/.test(addressPoints1[i][2]) ? 5: 1);
    leafletView.RegisterMarker(m);
}

for (var i = 0, l = addressPoints2.length; i < l; ++i) {
    var m = new PruneCluster.Marker(addressPoints2[i][0], addressPoints2[i][1], {title: addressPoints2[i][2]},/^\d+$/.test(addressPoints2[i][2]) ? 5: 1);
    leafletView.RegisterMarker(m);
}

...
```

The site I'm testing this on is [leaflet.ssecure.co](http://leaflet.ssecure.co).

If anyone knows how to work this out, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Removed the (useless) markers and big file tags and added PHP and MySQL tags (mysql is a guess) since you're always having this problem even without using the index.php with jquery/leaflet: http://leaflet.ssecure.co/markers.php?n=100000 works and http://leaflet.ssecure.co/markers.php?n=1000000 doesn't. Your problem lies souly with PHP/MySQL

Comment: @iH8 I added the try/catch statements but I never get any exceptions. Maybe the MySQL database has a memory limit for select queries?

Comment: Did you check your webserver's errorlog?

Comment: @iH8 Yes I did and it says "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/propertyregistration.com/leaflet.ssecure.co/lib.php on line 96" I guess I need to increase the memory limit to 512mb.

Comment: You could have seen that error on screen if you had your errors configured correctly like i said in my answer, would have saved you a lot of time. But you're correct, you'll need to up your memory limit, you could start with 256MB though and see if that works.

Comment: @iH8 Ok, so I set the memory limit to 1,536MB and still it doesn't go above 400,000 markers. Also, I checked the error logs and it doesn't show anything from the last 30 minutes. I also set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and still no errors.

Comment: @iH8 I also set `ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');` in php.ini and lib.php.

Comment: If you're getting no errors, i really wouldn't know

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your (markers) PHP file. Please make sure you have `display_errors` enabled and your `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` so PHP will throw an error instead of returning with a blank 500 server error. You could also check your webserver error log.

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

My guess is that your DB fails since it returns 100000 markers without a hitch, so you could also put a try/catch block around your actual query to see if that throws any exception which currently slips through.